# Projected / enumerated array returns last element copied to all other elements

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, nunit, moq

I'm not sure if this is a Moq problem, or I've done something blindly obvious and I've just been looking at it for too long.

I'm getting some really weird results with the following statement:

```
var orderedFiles = files
    .Select(p => {
        var post = _serializer.Deserialize<BlogPostModel>(_fs.File.ReadAllText(p));
        post.FileDate = GetFileNameDate(p);
        post.FilePath = p;
        return post;
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.FileDate);
```

When I enumerate this, (by using orderedFiles.ToArray() or .ToList()) I'm getting the LAST element in the original "files" array returned back for all elements in the enumerable. So, for the test below, I'm getting the projected file5 values, 5 times.

When I put breakpoints within the Select() method call each iteration is returning the correct values. After I enumerate, the values are all the same - screenshots below:

[image: The projected values are returned correctly]

Above: The projected values are returned correctly from the Select() - each iteration returns a completely different object.

[image: The enumerated values are all equal to the last element of the original GetFiles() call]

Above: The enumerated values are all equal to the last element of the original GetFiles() call, as you can see by the two expanded elements in the Locals window.

Here's my test (the mocks are inserted into the service when GetService() is called, and a number of global setups are put together in the nunit SetUp method):

```
[Test]
public void GetBlogPosts_PicksUpFilesInReverseFileNameDateOrder() {
    // Arrange
    var file1 = Path.Combine(blogPathContent, "2013-12-28-04-31-41-this-is-the-blog-title-1.json"); // 2
    var file2 = Path.Combine(blogPathContent, "2013-10-09-01-54-43-this-is-the-blog-title-2.json"); // 3
    var file3 = Path.Combine(blogPathContent, "2014-01-12-18-52-32-this-is-the-blog-title-3.json"); // 1
    var file4 = Path.Combine(blogPathContent, "2012-12-20-06-18-23-this-is-the-blog-title-5.json"); // 5
    var file5 = Path.Combine(blogPathContent, "2013-06-04-12-28-56-this-is-the-blog-title-4.json"); // 4

    mockSerializer
        .Setup(x => x.Deserialize<BlogPostModel>(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(new BlogPostModel());

    mockDirectory
        .Setup(x => x.GetFiles(It.Is<string>(s => s == blogPathContent),
            It.Is<string>(s => s == string.Concat("*", blogFilesExt))))
        .Returns(new[] {file1, file2, file3, file4, file5});

    service = GetService();

    // Act
    var actualResult = service.GetBlogPosts(new GetBlogPostsRequest());

    // Assert
    //mockFile1.VerifyGet(x => x.FullName, Times.Exactly(5), "FullName should have been called exactly 5 times.");
    Assert.NotNull(actualResult.BlogList, "BlogList should not be null");
    Assert.NotNull(actualResult.BlogList.BlogPosts, "BlogPosts should not be null");
    Assert.True(actualResult.Success, "Success should be true");
    Assert.IsNull(actualResult.Message, "Message should be null");
    Assert.AreEqual(5, actualResult.BlogList.BlogPosts.Length, "5 blog posts are expected");

    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2014, 1, 12, 18, 52, 32), actualResult.BlogList.BlogPosts[0].FileDate, "file3 should be pos 1");
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2013, 12, 28, 4, 31, 41), actualResult.BlogList.BlogPosts[1].FileDate, "file1 should be pos 2");
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2013, 10, 9, 1, 54, 43), actualResult.BlogList.BlogPosts[2].FileDate, "file2 should be pos 3");
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2012, 12, 20, 6, 18, 23), actualResult.BlogList.BlogPosts[4].FileDate, "file4 should be pos 5");
    Assert.AreEqual(new DateTime(2013, 6, 4, 12, 28, 56), actualResult.BlogList.BlogPosts[3].FileDate, "file5 should be pos 4");
}
```

And here's the implementation code:

```
public GetBlogPostsResponse GetBlogPosts(GetBlogPostsRequest req)
{
    var files = _fs.Directory.GetFiles(contentPath, string.Concat("*", blogFilesExtension));
    if (files == null || files.Length <= 0) {
        return new GetBlogPostsResponse {
            Success = false,
            Message = "No blog posts have been made"
        };
    }

    // Deserialize / map each message
    var orderedFiles = files
        .Select(p => {
            var post = _serializer.Deserialize<BlogPostModel>(_fs.File.ReadAllText(p));
            post.FileDate = GetFileNameDate(p);
            post.FilePath = p;
            return post;
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.FileDate);

    var posts = orderedFiles.ToArray();
    var response = new GetBlogPostsResponse {
        Success = true,
        BlogList = new BlogListModel {
            // BUG: enumerating here is returning a copy of the last element of the array for all elements
            BlogPosts = posts
        }
    };

    return response;
}
```

Have I missed something obvious? I've checked all the mocks are set up right, and the above debugging seems to suggest that either the ToArray() method is playing funny beggars... but that's not possible, right? :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical - sorted it! If anything, posting on SO makes me take a break and come back to it later.

This makes sense now I've figured it out... I modified the following test line:

```
mockSerializer
    .Setup(x => x.Deserialize<BlogPostModel>(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(new BlogPostModel());
```

To the following:

```
mockSerializer
    .Setup(x => x.Deserialize<BlogPostModel>(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(() => new BlogPostModel());
```

Had to return new BlogPostModel() via the plain lambda override. Looks like Moq will re-use the value returned from a Setup if you don't explicitly tell it to return a unique value each time - which explains why it was always returning the last element - because each element of the enumeration was just a reference to the object returned from Moq.

Phew!

Comment: Correct. In the original version, with `.Returns(new BlogPostModel())`, the `new` object-creation expression is evaluated *before* the call to `Returns` and the value of it (which is a reference to the newly created instance) is what is passed to `Returns`. So the `Returns` method gets no expression or anything, just a reference to a specific concrete instance, so it cannot do anything other than returning that reference every time.